# How to apply jquery time picker in dynamic created element(Add more button)?

Tags: jquery

I am using [jquery time picker](https://github.com/Sonelal/jquery-timepicker). It display time drop downs for all elements, but when I apply this on dynamically created text field (dynamically creating form element by javascript with "Add More" button) it doesn't works.

Below is the code which I implement.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../include/jquery_time_picker/jquery.timepicker.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../include/jquery_time_picker/jquery.timepicker.css" />
<script>

$(function() {
     $(".Time_Pic").timepicker();
});

function add_more_element()
{
   //code for creating form elements
}
</script>
```

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your add function try like this

```
function add_more_element()
{
    //code for creating form elements
   //add element here like
    $('div').append("<input type='text' class='time'>");
    $('.time').timtpicker();
}
```

Comment: $('.time').timepicker(); - not timtpicker()

Answer (score 3):

I would call it inside your `add_more_element()` function

```
function add_more_element()
{
//code for creating form elements
    $(".Time_Pic").timepicker();
}
```

This way, every time a new element is created, the `timepicker` is applied to it

Comment: No problem, hit the check mark if you think this is the answer

Comment: This doesn't work. I put an alert() in my iterator to show the new element name, but the time picker won't work.